# EF Trying to Insert Foreign Key Value into Primary Key Field

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have the following two entities defined. A `ResponseSeries` can have a related `TabletUserSession`. It's a fairly straight forward one-to-zero-or-one relationship.

```
public class ResponseSeries : TrackedEntity
{
    public ResponseSeries()
    {
        Responses = new Collection<Response>();
    }
    public Int32 ResponseSeriesId { get; set; }

    public virtual TabletUserSession TabletUserSession { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class TabletUserSession : TrackedEntity
{
    public Int32 TabletUserSessionId { get; set; }
    public Int32 ResponseSeriesId { get; set; }
    public Int32? TabletId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Tablet Tablet { get; set; }
    public virtual ResponseSeries ResponseSeries { get; set; }
}
```

I configure the mapping like so:

```
public TabletUserSessionMap()
{
    HasRequired(tus => tus.ResponseSeries).WithOptional(rs => rs.TabletUserSession);
}
```

When I try to create a new `ResponseSeries` and a new `TabletUserSession` for it like so:

```
responseSeries.TabletUserSession = new TabletUserSession
{
    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
    TabletId = request.TabletId,
};

context.ResponseSeries.Add(responseSeries);
context.SaveChanges();
```

An error is thrown when inserting `TabletUserSession` because EF tries to insert the `ResponseSeriesId` into `TabletUserSessionId`.

```
INSERT [dbo].[TabletUserSession]
       ([TabletUserSessionId],
        [ResponseSeriesId],
        [TabletId],
        [StartDate],
        [ClosedDate],
        [Version],
        [CreatedUserId],
        [CreatedDate],
        [LastUpdateUserId],
        [LastUpdateDate])
VALUES (4404 /* @0 */, -- <--This is going into the wrong field!
        0 /* @1 */,
        9 /* @2 */,
        '2014-03-06T13:30:03' /* @3 */,
        NULL,
        1 /* @4 */,
        '801162722' /* @5 */,
        '2014-03-06T13:30:03' /* @6 */,
        '801162722' /* @7 */,
        '2014-03-06T13:30:03' /* @8 */)
```

I'm at wits end here. I've tried changing the mapping in various ways, but all I can do is get it to throw different exceptions. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one-to-one relationship to exist. The primary key is the same on both entities.

On the dependent table, the primary key is also the foreign key to the related entity.

In your example:

```
public class ResponseSeries : TrackedEntity
{
    public ResponseSeries()
    {
        Responses = new Collection<Response>();
    }
    public Int32 ResponseSeriesId { get; set; }

    public virtual TabletUserSession TabletUserSession { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }

}

public class TabletUserSession : TrackedEntity
{
    // this should not exist
    public Int32 TabletUserSessionId { get; set; }

    // this should be the primary key of this entity
    // it is also the foreign key to the ResponseSeriesId
    public Int32 ResponseSeriesId { get; set; }
    public Int32? TabletId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Tablet Tablet { get; set; }
    public virtual ResponseSeries ResponseSeries { get; set; }
}
```

ResponseSeriesId is the primary key and is the prinicpal entity in the relationship. In this case, the primary key of your TabletUserSession entity needs to be ResponseSeriesId. It does not have an identity of its own, because otherwise it's not really one to zero or one.

Comment: Any way to make this work without changing the data model? Maybe set it up as if it's a one to many?

Comment: Sure, if you set it up as a one to many relationship it would work fine. ResponseSeries would have an ICollection<TabletUserSession> instead of a single item. You could have some business logic that would throw an exception if you tried to add a second item perhaps.

Comment: Yeah it's ugly, but ugly is what we sometimes have to do when working with existing databases, right?

I added the TabletUserSessions collection property and alongside it I added an ignored TabletUserSession property that gives me easy access to the collection's sole member. If I were really thorough, I could write a custom ICollection implementation that only allows one member, but I'm not that thorough.

I'll definitely keep EF's one-to-one convention in mind for new development. Thanks for your help!